# how to display the integer input into String after execute?

Tags: java, string, integer

this is a simple coding i need to do.. the problem is, after running, it will display for example, "Today is 2 and 2 day later is Thursday." instead of "Today is Tuesday and 2 days later is Thursday."

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindFutureDay {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Variable
    int day, next, future;

    //Create scanner
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    //Input day
    System.out.println("Enter day today: ");
    day=input.nextInt();
    //Convert day to String
    String Sunday = String.valueOf(0);
    String Monday = String.valueOf(1);
    String Tuesday = String.valueOf(2);
    String Wednesday = String.valueOf(3);
    String Thursday = String.valueOf(4);
    String Friday = String.valueOf(5);
    String Saturday = String.valueOf(6);


    //Input number of days later
    System.out.println("Number of days later: ");
    next=input.nextInt();

    //Close scanner
    input.close();

    //Compute future day
    future=day+next;

    //Select result to display
    if (future%7==0){
        System.out.println("Today is "+day+" and "+next+" day later is Sunday.");
    } else if (future%7==1) {
        System.out.printf("Today is "+day+" and "+next+" day later is Monday.");
    } else if (future%7==2) {
        System.out.printf("Today is "+day+" and "+next+" day later is Tuesday.");
    } else if (future%7==3) {
        System.out.println("Today is "+day+" and "+next+" day later is Wednesday.");
    } else if (future%7==4) {
        System.out.println("Today is "+day+" and "+next+" day later is Thursday.");
    } else if (future%7==5) {
        System.out.println("Today is "+day+" and "+next+" day later is Friday.");
    } else if (future%7==6) {
        System.out.println("Today is "+day+" and "+next+" day later is Saturday.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid!");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your "problem" is the you print integer therefor you get a numeric print.
you can fix that for example by adding a function getDay(day) instead of day.

```
private String GetDay (int day)
   { 


 if (day == 1)
       {
           return "Sunday";
       }

   return null;


   }


System.out.println("Today is "+GetDay (int day) +" and "+next+" day later is Sunday.");
```

The same logic apply to next integer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you Sunday to Saturday variables are never used and do not store days as String anyway but a String representation of the corresponding integer. Therefore, you will never be able to print "Tuesday" instead of "2" because you simply print the variable 'day', which is the scanned integer.

You should store a map and get the String representation from its integer value. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindFutureDay {

    private static Map<Integer, String> weekDays = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    static {
        weekDays.put(0, "Sunday");
        weekDays.put(1, "Monday");
        weekDays.put(2, "Tuesday");
        weekDays.put(3, "Wednesday");
        weekDays.put(4, "Thursday");
        weekDays.put(5, "Friday");
        weekDays.put(6, "Saturday");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Variable
       int day, next, future;

       //Create scanner
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

       //Input day
       System.out.println("Enter day today: ");
       day = input.nextInt();

       //Input number of days later
       System.out.println("Number of days later: ");
       next = input.nextInt();

       //Close scanner
       input.close();

       //Compute future day
       future = (day + next) % 7;

       //Select result to display
       System.out.println("Today is " + weekDays.get(day) + " and " + next + " day later is " + weekDays.get(future) + ".");
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.